# Text Outline coming up as less than 1pt for pre press

Tags: text, prepress

[image: Picture of 1pt line next to 6.03 text yes problem]
[image: picture of 1pt line next to 4.2 text no problem]

So I'm working on an album for a 12 inch record.
The printer has a preflight profile that I have to pass through before uploading to their site and printing the job for obvious reasons.

My issue is that there is a stipulation with the preflight that no lines can be stroked to less than 1pt.
My 'working' file passed the preflight, so I command A create outlines for the type and save as 'final' for the printer and slept on it until its due thinking everything is set.

The final is not passing the preflight because the letter 'i' is coming up as less than one pt. only the letter 'i'. The text is 6.03 pt or something before outlines. The text is white knockout on black backdrop (from a photo faded to a rich black) to prevent artifacting etc.

The font is the record labels signature font, and I am aware that I can just include the font with the folder (as the printer requests) but my question is more that when I create outlines the text becomes a shape right? And there is not stroke on the shape so I'm confused as to why this error is coming up.

Ideally I'd like to avoid not outlining the text because its very expensive job to be printed, thousands of copies at a remote printer etc. I've used the printer before and used smaller text (but it was uppercase).

Pre press stress is the real struggle. 
Especially on this photo manip labor intensive cover.
S.o.s. please send help.

So the 1st photo is a 1pt line near the text that is an issue just the letter "i"

The second photo is a 1 pt line near non issure 4.2 text
The secon

Comment: a 1pt minimum seems rather large for a 12" record label.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @DA01 "When I when I create outlines the text becomes a shape right? So why is it saying there is a stroke on the shape, I've made smaller paths and have not had a problem for instance the periods are not coming up as a flag in the pre press just lowercase i's and there are foreign names that have umlaut

Comment: That means your "shapes", the "i", is not 1pts thickness. For some printing process, you cannot go below 1pt or that line with disappear or not appear properly. Your only option is to add a thin stroke to your vectorized letters until it's 1pt wide. To know if your letters are alright just trace a 1pt thick line to a vertical or horizontal part of your letter (outlined) and then make it as thick or thicker (eg. compare your letters with a normal 1pt thick line). The issue is not about the size of your letters, it's about how thick the letters are.

Comment: By the way, if you add a thin stroke to get to that 1pt thickness, do it to ALL the text, not only the "i"!

Comment: @go-me incorrect. all of the text has lines thinner than that of a 1.pt line. Trying to add screenshots (not sure how), but I have smaller 4pt text with no problem passing the preflight, but they're capital letters.

Comment: Upload your image at 100% or just the part that is problematic at 100%! Your printer use a preflight; preflight tells them you have less than 1pt for a reason. If that white vertical line is a 1pt stroke on your image, it's clear your text is not 1pt thick. Hard to tell without seeing a PDF or vector file. I still don't understand why a label would require this; usually that requirement is when printing on plastic or really on the vinyl. I guess your label is not printed on paper. It's weird indeed if the 4pts is alright, and the accents/special characters are alright on the lowercases too.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this. You need to take this back to the printer. It's very odd that 1pt is the minimum. That sounds like a pretty low-fidelity printing process (even the cheapest laser printer prints at a much higher resolution). I agree with go-me in that it sounds like the pre-flight software is flagging the i's *shape* as thinner than 1px. Maybe that's just a defect of the software. Or maybe it's not even an actual issue. You need to ask the printer.

Comment: (Though screen printing may have this restriction...but you are correct that it's odd that it'd only flag the 'i'. Seems like a software bug)

Comment: @DA01 I've already spoken with the prepress department

Here are the prepress guidlines
http://www.ross-ellis.com/en/general-guidelines.html

I wanted to solve the problem on my end because I don't like when people touch my files between design and printing other than turning dielines off

Comment: so...what did the prepress department say? Were they not able to help? Their guidelines don't make any sense...they allow 5pt type but insist that strokes be a minimum of 1pt. That's just plain nonsensical. At this point, it sounds like you just need to use much larger, or much bolder typefaces.

Comment: I would agree with @DA01 It's pretty odd to allow type smaller than 6pts but then restrict strokes to a minimum of 1pt.

Comment: @da01 they wanted the font to be sent to them with the proofs/links which I always do, just found it weird because they didnt really give me an answer before they pass it through preflight themselves (which why would it come up any differently IMO was a non answer). Anyway thanks for the help it's due this week probably tomorrow. Will update if I find a solution, was hoping someone would've ran into a similar problem it does seem like a preflight glitch though. Thanks guys

Comment: It's not odd at all, most printers do not recommend smaller than 5pts font size, extra light style, 1pt stroke for some type of printing. @Andrew, if you want to "play safe", you will need to bold your fonts and stick to their requirements. You can still send your files as they are but the printer won't be able to take any responsibility in the quality of the final printed product. It sucks but you'll need to fix your design to fit their requirements or find another printer. But Transcontinental Media is a huge company, they know what they're doing.

Comment: @go-me but don't you find those two statements contradictory? Most type at 5pt is going to have strokes much smaller than 1pt.

Comment: No I don't. That's why it's suggested to not use a font smaller than 5pts size. A helvetica neue extended black @ 4-5pts size has the 1pt thickness for sure. An ultra light @12pts, maybe not. These requirements help to avoid that kind of mistake and offer some precise guideline for any kind of situation. And they are the same for an illustration too (unfortunately!) It's very challenging for all designers and it limits the options for the layout, I can't deny this!